# Acceptance of Terms and Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I know that there have been a few other posts on this topic, but I have tried their solutions and they don't work. I have a devise user model, and this model has a boolean called `:terms_and_conditions`. I want to prevent a user from signing up on my website unless they have checked this terms and conditions box. By checking the box, the user's boolean attribute should be set to true. With my current code, a user can sign up without checking the box, and checking the box does not affect the boolean field. How can I fix this?

devise/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <%= f.check_box :terms_and_conditions %><strong> I accept the terms and conditions<strong>
  </label>
</div>
```

models/user.rb:

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms_and_conditions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in models/user.rb:
validates_presence_of :terms_and_conditions

Answer (score 0):

set `validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true`, and see if that fixes your problem. read more about it at rails guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: Found the problem. I added the :terms_and_conditions to my devise parameter sanitizer. But now, no matter what I do, it says terms and conditions must be accepted (even if it is). It doesn't seem to register that if it is checked, the value is true

Comment: yea, when using devise you need to permit it too. well at least it you solve your problem.

Comment: No, the problem is not completely solved. Now, no matter what I do, it says terms and conditions must be accepted (even if it is). It doesn't seem to register that if it is checked, the value is true.